# how to move two windows forms together?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've main form when I press btn I open new form with showDialog()  function,
I need to move two forms together when I press on main form, because they share in 
design.
how can I move them together either I press on main form and move it or I press on form2 and move it?
Thx alot for any suggestion.

Comment: Interesting UI - why two forms rather than one, if they're tied so closely together?

Comment: yes Will A good point, because in fact I've lots of functionality in form1 and form2 also has lots of panels to do other several functions and it's really a different form ,the idea that the main form Represents main interface and the background to other forms that open inside it, it still appear when I open form2 inside it.

Comment: @Will-A: Sounds like a loose-window approach similar to PhotoShop, GIMP, or even VS2010.

Comment: mmm So wh your sugg? ,!
I'm using 
MainFrm_MouseDown
MainFrm_MouseMove
in main form to move it,'because it's formBorderStyle=none'
so do I need to make these sub as public then call theme from frm2 or there is other ways to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a separate class to manage the form connections and event handling.

```
class FormConnector
{
    private Form mMainForm;

    private List<Form> mConnectedForms = new List<Form>();

    private Point mMainLocation;

    public FormConnector(Form mainForm)
    {
        this.mMainForm = mainForm;
        this.mMainLocation = new Point(this.mMainForm.Location.X, this.mMainForm.Location.Y);
        this.mMainForm.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(MainForm_LocationChanged);
    }

    public void ConnectForm(Form form)
    {
        if (!this.mConnectedForms.Contains(form))
        {
            this.mConnectedForms.Add(form);
        }
    }

    void MainForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point relativeChange = new Point(this.mMainForm.Location.X - this.mMainLocation.X, this.mMainForm.Location.Y - this.mMainLocation.Y);
        foreach (Form form in this.mConnectedForms)
        {
            form.Location = new Point(form.Location.X + relativeChange.X, form.Location.Y + relativeChange.Y);
        }

        this.mMainLocation = new Point(this.mMainForm.Location.X, this.mMainForm.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to instantiate a FormConnector and call ConnectForm method with the form you want to connect to.

Comment: I like this it works well for what I need.
But How would you add Form.Acive event to it?

What I need is to ensure only the main form ever has focus and is top most in the ZOrder?

Comment: @Adrian: You can attach a handler to the Activated event of the newly added form. In that event handler you just call the Activate and BringToFront methods on the main form.

Answer (score 0):

The main ingredients are the forms' `Top`, `Left`, `Location`, and `Width` properties. Say you have a reference to both forms, called `form1` and `form2`. You could reposition windows like so:

```
form2.Location = new Point(form1.Left + form1.Width, form1.Top);
```

The result is both forms, top aligned, with form2 on the right.

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420.aspx

Comment: thx kbrimington,but wh I mean,I open frm2 with frm2.showDialog() so,
is this way work with me to move main and frm2 together when I press on main form to move it?

Comment: @Dani-AM: Add an event handler to each form's `LocationChanged` event. In the event handler, reposition the opposite form as described above. If you do this in both forms, check the opposite form position prior to updating its location, so as to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: @Dani-AM: Great. Consider, also, adding handlers to the `SizeChanged` event if your forms are resizable.

Comment: really appreciate your Follow up @kbrimington ;)